# How to process data from one stream and return it as another async stream in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, asynchronous

I'm writing a ASP.NET Web API (.NET 7). I need to create an service that loads specified data via a stream, does something to it on-the-fly and then returns it as a stream.

Let's say this is the method definition in a `StreamEncoder` service class:

```cs
public async Task<Stream> EncodeStream(Stream input);
```

What that method needs to do is:

1. Immediately return the output stream
2. Keep loading input stream data in chunks (for example 32 bytes)
3. Process that chunk by encoding it into Base64
4. Pass that encoded chunk to the output stream.

The idea is that later this service can be used withing the API endpoint. Something like this:

```cs
[HttpGet("image")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage([FromQuery] string url, [FromQuery] string format)
{
    // Perform checks ...
    
    // Load stream
    url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
    var imageStream = await _imageLoaderService.LoadImage(url);
    if (imageStream is null) return NotFound();

    // Start processing the stream
    var outputStream = await _streamEncoder(imageStream);

    // Return immediately
    return File(outputStream, Formats[format]);
}
```

Processing streams synchronously in batches is pretty simple, but I can't seem to find a solution for processing on-the-fly, so that the API client starts receiving data before the server had a chance to finish loading all of it's data.

[image: Sequence diagram presenting the data flow]

Very often the input data is over 500MB in size and I need to be processing several of them at the same time. I can't just load all of data to RAM, then process it and at the end return the result.

How can I solve this problem? Are there any libraries that would help with it?

Comment: It's probably easier to transform chunks of data in your own `ICryptoTransform` implementation, then return a `CryptoStream`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thanks! I'll look into their implementations.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things in play here.

First, streaming responses come with a couple of limitations.

The HTTP response is comprised of headers followed by the data. Since the status code is returned as a header value, the first limitation of streaming responses is that you cannot change the status code. In order to stream a response, your API must return 200 and *then* stream. If you're streaming along and the upstream has an error, then there's no way to change that status code to a 502 or 500; all you can do is throw an exception and then ASP.NET will clamp the connection shut, which *most* clients will interpret as an error (some kind of general "communications error", not a 500).

The other limitation is that your code may not know the length of the response until after it's sent. This is especially true since there is encoding being done. So this means your response won't have a `Content-Length` header, which means no nice progress updates for your clients.

But if you're OK with those limitations, then the specifics of how to do a streaming response come into play.

You can start streaming by calling `StartAsync` and *then* copy to the stream, as such:

```
[HttpGet("image")]
public async Task GetImage([FromQuery] string url, [FromQuery] string format)
{
  // Load stream
  url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
  var imageStream = await _imageLoaderService.LoadImage(url);
  if (imageStream is null)
  {
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return;
  }

  // Set all the response headers.
  Response.StatusCode = 200;
  Response.ContentType = Formats[format];
  Response.Headers[...] = ...

  // Send the headers and start streaming.
  await Response.StartAsync();

  // Process the stream. This is just a straight copy as an example.
  await imageStream.CopyToAsync(Response.Body);
}
```

Note that you do lose the nice `IAsyncResult` helpers with this approach. (In particular, if you're using `File` and friends to set `Content-Disposition`, then the `IAsyncResult` helpers handle all the tedious header value encoding that is necessary). If you want to keep the `IAsyncResult` helpers, then you can't use `StartAsync` directly. In that case I recommend you write your own `IAsyncResult` type.

I have a [`FileCallbackResult` type on GitHub](https://github.com/StephenClearyExamples/AsyncDynamicZip/blob/72bd39e433d6dbf4b1aca9a9d1d1b5e5909ac5b9/Example/src/WebApplication/FileCallbackResult.cs) that passes the output stream to a callback. Using my type would look like this:

```
[HttpGet("image")]
public async Task<IAsyncResult> GetImage([FromQuery] string url, [FromQuery] string format)
{
  // Load stream
  url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
  var imageStream = await _imageLoaderService.LoadImage(url);
  if (imageStream is null)
    return NotFound();

  return new FileCallbackResult(Formats[format], async (stream, context) =>
  {
    // Process the stream. This is just a straight copy as an example.
    await imageStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
  });
}
```

*Technically,* it would also be possible to write a producer/consumer stream, but this would be more work. No type like that currently exists (except `NetworkStream`, but you can't control both sides of that one). In the past, this would have been considerably difficult, but today I think you could do it using pipelines. Pipelines are a more modern and more efficient form of stream that also support producer/consumer semantics. Once you had a producer/consumer stream, then you could pass it to the standard `File` helper method. The only tricky part is error handling: you'd have to be sure that your producer delegate was wrapped in a top-level `try`/`catch` and would capture and re-raise any exception to the consumer.

**Update**: Indeed, creating a producer/consumer stream is [not difficult](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/42bb5144529ef52f596b07979c488f47) due to pipelines:

```
public sealed class ProducerConsumerStream
{
    public static Stream Create(Func<Stream, Task> producer, PipeOptions? options = null)
    {
        var pipe = new Pipe(options ?? PipeOptions.Default);
        var readStream = pipe.Reader.AsStream();
        var writeStream = pipe.Writer.AsStream();
        Run();
        return readStream;

        async void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                await producer(writeStream);
                await writeStream.FlushAsync();
                pipe.Writer.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                pipe.Writer.Complete(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage (note that real-world usage should specify `PipeOptions.PauseWriterThreshold`):

```
public Stream EncodeStream(Stream input)
{
  return ProducerConsumerStream.Create(async output =>
  {
    // Process the stream. This is just a straight copy as an example.
    await input.CopyToAsync(output);
  });
}

[HttpGet("image")]
public async Task<IAsyncResult> GetImage([FromQuery] string url, [FromQuery] string format)
{
  // Load stream
  url = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(url);
  var imageStream = await _imageLoaderService.LoadImage(url);
  if (imageStream is null)
    return NotFound();

  var outputStream = _streamEncoder.EncodeStream(imageStream);
  return File(outputStream, Formats[format]);
}
```